# spring boot ssl certificate from godaddy not working

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

i am running a spring boot application locally and bought a ssl certificate to be able to use https
but it is not working .. steps i made
downloaded the zip folder from godaddy
using keytool i generated the cert.p12 and added to the resources  folder  in the project

```
but everytime i run the code it gives an exception 
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-07-18T16:15:53.842-04:00 ERROR 12004 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.codeyai.CodeyaiApplication.main(CodeyaiApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:44) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:235) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1043) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:232) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alias name [codeyai] does not identify a key entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:70) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1342) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:633) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1041) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [codeyai] does not identify a key entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:336) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:246) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:104) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Process finished with exit code 1

i tried multi times till i got fedup and decided to try with self sined cert
and it worked right away with the same steps
have any one used a cert other that self signed cert???

i tried multi times till i got fed up and decided to try with self singed cert
and it worked right away with the same steps
have any one used a cert other that self signed cert???

Comment: I think your question does not give enough information. What is your folder structure where you placed the certs, where is the server config pushing to https? How do we know the certs are right, what GoDaddy commands did you run? There are more things to question than to answer here, I'd revise your question

Comment: it is a spring boot and i am placing the .p12 generated from the keytool in the springboot resource folder. there is no command to run in godaddy .. its the strandedcert they have. and at first i used the csr generated by them and i also generated my csr and rekey the certificate but it still gave the same error above

Comment: What I am saying is that you only showing your error log, is only showing where the error is...not what it is. The only line in your traceback that does not appear to be basic framework passthrough is: `com.codeyai.CodeyaiApplication.main(CodeyaiApplication.java:11)`...so what is your `main` method doing in `CodeyaiApplication`? In overview you have essentially shown an error, i.e. (as an example not this actual case, it just makes more sense as this is a known error) a `NullPointerException`, but you have not shown the code causing the error, which is how it can be debugged

Comment: lets take it in  another direction do u know how to enable ssl for a spring boot application? what steps do u take and where do u get the cert from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

how to get an ssl cert from authority for springboot*

---

1)download openssl to get the csr

To generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) on Windows 10, you can use OpenSSL, which is a widely-used open-source toolkit for SSL/TLS. Follow these steps:

```
Download and install OpenSSL for Windows:
    Visit the OpenSSL website: https://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html
    Scroll down to the "Win64 OpenSSL v*" section and download the appropriate installer for your Windows 10 version.

Install OpenSSL:
    Run the downloaded OpenSSL installer.
    Follow the on-screen instructions to install OpenSSL on your Windows 10 system.

Open the OpenSSL Command Prompt:
    Press the Windows key, type "OpenSSL", and select "OpenSSL Command Prompt" from the search results.
    This will open a command prompt window with OpenSSL preconfigured.

Generate the CSR:
    In the OpenSSL Command Prompt, navigate to the directory where you want to generate the CSR.
    Run the following command to generate the CSR:

    
    openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout private.key -out csr.pem

    Replace private.key with the desired name for your private key file.
    Replace csr.pem with the desired name for your CSR file.

Provide the requested information:
    OpenSSL will prompt you to enter various pieces of information for the CSR.
    Enter the information as prompted, including the Common Name (CN), Organization (O), Organizational Unit (OU), Locality (L), State (ST), and Country (C).
    The Common Name (CN) should be the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) for which you are requesting the certificate.

Verify and save the generated CSR:
    Review the generated CSR information for accuracy.
    Save the private key (private.key) securely. This key will be used to install the issued certificate on your server.
```

You have now generated a CSR on Windows 10 using OpenSSL. You can provide the generated CSR to your certificate provider (such as GoDaddy) to complete the certificate issuance process.

2. once you have the csr you go to godaddy and paste both the .key and the .pem generated fromthe openssl either in rekey or in the initial csr when u buy a new crt

   - then when you DOWNLOAD THE CERT CHOOSE TOMCAT FROMTHE DOPE DOWN
     CONVERT THE PEM CERT TO .P12
     unzip the folder downloaded it will have .pem and .crt
     create a file that combine the .key"PRIVATE KEY given by openssl" and the  .pem"THE CERT downloaded from godaddy" {name it combine.pem}

     Run the following OpenSSL command to generate the PKCS12 keystore:

     ```
      openssl pkcs12 -export -in combined.pem -out keystore.p12 -name your_certificate_alias
     ```

     Replace combined.pem with the path to your combined PEM file, and your_certificate_alias with the desired alias name for your certificate.
     During the conversion process, you will be prompted to set a password for the PKCS12 keystore. Make sure to remember this password as you will need it later.

   Place the keystore.p12 file in a secure location, either within your Spring Boot project or on your server.

   Configure the SSL properties in your Spring Boot application's configuration file (e.g., application.properties or application.yml):

   ```
    For application.properties:

    properties
   ```

   server.port=8443
   server.ssl.enabled=true
   server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
   server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
   server.ssl.key-store-password=your_keystore_password
   server.ssl.key-alias=your_certificate_alias

   For application.yml:

   yaml

   ```
        server:
          port: 8443
          ssl:
            enabled: true
            key-store-type: PKCS12
            key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
            key-store-password: your_keystore_password
            key-alias: your_certificate_alias

    Replace keystore.p12 with the path to your keystore file, your_keystore_password with the password you set during the keystore conversion, and your_certificate_alias with the desired alias name for your certificate.

    Run your Spring Boot application, and it will use the configured SSL settings to serve HTTPS requests on the specified port (in this case, 8443).
   ```

Make sure to have the necessary files (combined.pem and keystore.p12) in the correct locations and that the configuration properties are accurate.